# Why submitting pwrite request using io_submit API is much slower than submitting pread request?

Tags: c++, io, aio

I have an application that reads large amount of data from the disk and also writes a lot. I'm trying to use direct io to improve the I/O performance.

Now I'm using `libaio` to implement the asynchronous IO, both for read and write. The preliminary result shows improvement in reading stage but great drop in writing stage.

Then I used `strace` to capture the run time behavior and here is the reading stage log(I have deleted some unrelated log):

```
8509  20:59:03.005920 io_submit(139876672323584, 16, {{pread, filedes:102, buf:0x7f36bf816000, nbytes:524288, offset:96468992}} <unfinished ...>
8509  20:59:03.007236 <... io_submit resumed> ) = 16 <0.000893>
```

and here is the writing stage log:

```
8098  20:47:40.219194 io_submit(140277578346496, 1, {{pwrite, filedes:116, str:"\177\362\215\264\252\360\240\306\377?\265\36/\215#%\304\0343\300\230\256\3550\374 k\316\v\225\327\""..., nbytes:524288, offset:24117248}}) = 1 <0.002457>
```

Generally the same `io_submit` API takes various time. Even though submitting 16 read requests at one time, it's still faster than submitting 1 write request.

So is it right? How can I optimize my write stage?

Comment: It's not surprising that write is slower than read. Depending of a lot parameter (filesystem, technologie of support, ....), you can have a reallocation of memory (and so finding new place), maybe a slow erase phase before rewriting, .... In opposite, read is a "simple" access request.

Comment: What filesystem?  What disk controller?  What disk(s)?  How are the disk(s) partitioned?  Is there a RAID array?  How is that configured?  Are disk IO operations aligned with disk blocks?

Comment: Another way of using any async i/o on your OS which a lot of people forget about is to simply use memory mapped file sections. Truncate file B to the correct size, map in file A and file B, call memcpy(), do maps in sliding 10Mb windows if the file is big. On almost every OS out there this will perform an optimally efficient i/o pattern, an enormous amount of kernel tuning has been invested to ensure excellent performance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open your file with `O_DIRECT` and were you writing a to a fully allocated file? If not then `io_submit()` can easily start taking a long time by essentially turning into a blocking call. See one of the [answers to asynchronous IO io_submit latency in Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377629/2732969) for some of the things that must be done for `io_submit()` to perform properly.