# Is there a real asynchronous file accessor in java?

Tags: java, linux, asynchronous, storage

I want to read/write to a raw device(which is just a file in linux) asyncly, and I have been using `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel`.

But it's a 'fake asynchronous', because the AsynchronousFileChannel uses a thread pool to execute the read/write tasks. It's actually calling the synchronized read/write interface offered by OS.

What I really want is a real asynchronous implementation which is `io_submit` in linux.

But I can't find it in jdk or any other repositories like guava or apache.

So my question is this :

1. In java, is there an existing implementation of asynchronous file accessor based on the native `io_submit` interface ?
2. If not, why can't I see anyone else who need it ?

Comment: Wouldn't this go against the very "platform-independent" nature of Java?

Comment: rmlan, there could be an asynchronous implementation which used io_submit on Linux and threads on platforms which didn't support that mechanism -- it doesn't have to break platform independence.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What will this allow you to do that `AsynchronousFileChannel` doesn't?

Comment: Here's some discussion: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-discuss/2011-July/000581.html

Comment: @tgdavies, thanks, I saw this discussion. But the reason I want this is that if I turn off the file system cache and the disk buffer, the threads' implementation can't give a good performance comparing to io_submit

Answer (score 1):

> In java, is there an existing implementation of asynchronous file accessor based on the native io_submit interface

Not in the default Java libraries at the time of writing (2019). I doubt there's much enthusiasm to implement an `io_submit()` Java wrapper in the default libraries because:

- `libaio`/KAIO is quirky. Linux's KAIO is fraught with constraints like only really being asynchronous when doing direct I/O (and even then [there are very elaborate rules which will turn submission synchronous if broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46377629/2732969) that go beyond the caller's control)
- There's no guarantee that `libaio` library itself would be around so you would have to bundle it with Java or otherwise reimplement it.

> If not, why can't I see anyone else who need it ?

People who need it that badly have recreated wrappers (e.g. see https://github.com/zrlio/jaio ). However supporting KAIO would be a Linux only thing and thus not that portable (which goes a bit against a key Java ethos).