# Is the user/kernel space copy in Linux read(2)/write(2) a general design in operating systems?

Tags: linux, operating-system, posix, system-calls, buffering

I have a multi-part question about Linux's read(2)/write(2) system calls:

**1.Where exactly is the copy behavior, as described in the title, stated?**

I've tried looking through the [Linux Manual Page(2)](http://man.he.net/man2/write) but didn't find this explicitly stated. Yet, [many discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61522457/21165336) claim that the man page "clearly states" this behavior.

**2.During the read/write(2) process, does the copy that takes place in the kernel space actually copy entries content of the page table?**

Textbooks on operating systems mention that memory management is done via page tables, which map memory to the file system. The page table is obviously a kernel-space object. *These two concepts are often not linked*: When discussing interfaces, people say 'read/write(2) involves a kernel-space copy,' and when discussing operating systems, they say 'memory is managed using page tables.'

3.As mentioned in the title, given that I have not found explicit information on this in textbooks on operating systems, I am curious: **Is the kernel-space copy during the read/write process a standard design, or is this something unique to Linux?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described in the [manual for "sendfile"](http://man.he.net/man2/sendfile). For `read` and `write`, copying is an implementation detail - the programmer doesn't necessary have to know it. For `sendfile`, it is part of rationale - it explains, what makes it different from the already existing calls.

In general, `read`/`write` can be implemented in one of three ways:

1. It copies to a kernel buffer and returns. The actual write is performed later. For `read` - the kernel pre-reads in advance, and the `read` syscall just copies the data.
2. It blocks until the operation is complete, possibly for millions of CPU cycles. The disk controller *might* read/write the data directly from/to user space, but it is not guaranteed: the buffer might not fit the conditions (size, RAM alignment, disk alignment, etc) for a direct memory access - in that case, a copy will be done anyway.
3. It returns immediately, the operation is performed later. The program must keep the buffer untouched, until the operation completes. It can still do a copy for the same reasons.

The manual allows for options 1 and 2, but in practice, 1 is the most used, as it is usually faster. On Windows, [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile)/[ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) also allows for option 3, but only if the program specifically requests it.

Page tables **do not** map anything to the filesystem - they map virtual addresses of the current process and the kernel to the physical addresses of RAM or device MMIO registers. The `write` might trigger a memory allocation of a file buffer, but otherwise, the file operations have nothing to do with page tables.

There is another system call - `mmap`. That system call modifies the page tables in such a way, that the kernel file buffer appears in your process memory. That way, you can directly modify the kernel-side buffers with normal memory reads and writes. The kernel then can order the disk controller to store them on the disk.